# What is the best way to ReadLine by Expression Tree?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

If I want to get a user input from Console to my Expression Tree. What is the best way to do it? and how to make variable 'name' duck typing?

Here are my code.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Linq;
using Microsoft.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ExpressionTree
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Expression> statements = new List<Expression>();

            // Output
            MethodInfo Write = typeof(System.Console).GetMethod("Write", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            ConstantExpression param = Expression.Constant("What is your name? ", typeof(string));
            Expression output = Expression.Call(null, Write, param);
            statements.Add(output);

            // Input
            MethodInfo ReadLine = typeof(System.Console).GetMethod("ReadLine");
            ParameterExpression exprName = Expression.Variable(typeof(String), "name");
            Expression exprReadLine = Expression.Call(null, ReadLine);

            // .NET 4.0 (DlR 0.9) from Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll
            // Expression.Assign and Expression.Scope
            ScopeExpression input = Expression.Scope(Expression.Assign(exprName, exprReadLine), exprName);
            statements.Add(input);

            // Create the lambda
            LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Block(statements));

            // Compile and execute the lambda
            lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression trees are designed to perform a fixed operation - in particular, the member-access is going to want a known `MemberInfo` (etc) at the point of expression tree creation (since they are immutable).

You could duplicate the [generated code from `dynamic`](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dynamic-objects-part1.html) if you are playing with 4.0, but to be honest, the better approach in this scenario is simply: don't use an expression tree.

Either reflection or `ComponentModel` (`TypeDescriptor`) would be ideal for this dynamic access to a member.

Also - calling `Compile` on something you use only once isn't saving any time, and using `DynamicInvoke` isn't either... you need to use the typed delegate form (`Invoke`).

Comment: @MarkGravell: I've come across your answers on expression trees and dynamic types and have found them very helpful. Thank you! I am however, stumped at [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24939618/938668). If you get the chance to have a look, I'd appreciate your thoughts on it.