# Creating an expression tree that uses a dynamically generated type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, expression, expression-trees

I have a fully initialized `MethodBuilder` and `EnumBuilder`. The `MethodBuilder` points to the entry point of a dynamic assembly. It has the following signature:

```
public static int Main (string [] args) {...}
```

The assembly generation code works fine and I can use `Reflection.Emit` to test it. Instead of emitting IL, I want to save the target code from an expression tree. It should:

- declare a enum variable
- assign it a value
- write to the console
- read pause the console
- return a enum value as an Int32

**EXPRESSION TREE:**

```
// Intention: Declare string [] args in the expression scope.
var arguments = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string []), "args");
// Intention: var code = default(MyDynamicEnum);
var code = Expression.Variable(builderEnum, "code");
// Intention: code = MyDynamicEnum.Two;
var assign = Expression.Assign(code, Expression.Constant(2, builderEnum));
// Intention: Console.WriteLine(args [0]);
var write = Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type [] { typeof(string) }), Expression.ArrayIndex(arguments, Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int))));
// Intention: Console.ReadKey(true);
var read = Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod("ReadKey", new Type [] { typeof(bool) }), Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool)));
// Intention: return ((int) code);
var @return = Expression.Constant(2, typeof(int));

// How to combine above expressions and create a function body?
var block = Expression.Block(arguments, code, assign, write, read, @return);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string [], int>>(block, new ParameterExpression [] { arguments });

lambda.CompileToMethod(builderMethod); // Error: Variable 'code' of type 'Type: MyDynamicEnum' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined.
```

The full code is available on [this GIST](https://gist.github.com/raheelasadkhan/ebdeb439f8e570aa5ef3). The error on the last line seems to make sense but I don't know how to fix it. The enumeration `MyDynamicEnum` is already created as a type but how do I import it into the expression tree context? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using the correct overload of `Expression.Block`.

In order to use variables in the expression scope, we have to specify:

```
Expression.Block(variables.ToArray(), queue);
```

where variables is an array of `ParameterExpression` types.

Comment: The expressions in the block don't have to be in a collection, you can use `params` for them. Only variables (but not method parameters!) have to be in a collection.

Comment: @svick: I know. My example was pretty long so arranging different segments into collections (queues) was more convenient.